# Generating a total within a query loop

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I have a simple query that pulls a list of records by their ID:

```
<cfquery name="resTotals" datasource="#datasource#">
   SELECT ticket_id
   FROM   closed_tickets
   WHERE  YEAR(closed_date) = '2017' 
   AND    ticket_type = 'residential' 
</cfquery>
```

I am then trying to loop through those ID's in another query of a different table so I can check for the existence of a payment record. The goal is to then total up all the payment records find to get a total amount in dollar of payments.

I have this query to do that but it is throwing an error: *Can't cast String [99.00] to a value of type [Array]*

```
<cfloop query="resTotals">
     <cfquery name="resPaymentTotals" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT payment_amount
        FROM   payments
        WHERE  ticket_id = #resTotals.ticket_id#
     </cfquery>

 </cfloop>

 Amount of Sales: $ #ArraySum(resPaymentTotals.payment_amount)#
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Because the value you're passing into ArraySum, (ie resPaymentTotals.payment_amount), isn't an array.

Comment: Aren't query results an array of values?

Comment: They are, but you are running more than query.

Comment: What type of a database? You may not need multiple queries to get the information you're after.

Comment: Just use sum() aggregate function in the required column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<cfset total = 0 >
<cfloop query="resTotals">
     <cfquery name="resPaymentTotals" datasource="#datasource#">
     select payment_amount
     from payments
     where ticket_id = #resTotals.ticket_id#
     </cfquery>
 <cfset total = total + resPaymentTotals.payment_amount >
 </cfloop>
 Amount of Sales: $ #total#
```

Comment: That throw an error: can't cast empty string to a number value . Should I use NumberFormat() for variable total?

Comment: What is the data type of your payment column?

Comment: @BrianFleishman - Most likely one of the payment values is NULL. CF treats those as an empty string, causing an error when used in the addition operation `total + resPaymentTotals.payment_amount`. One solution is to wrap the query value in `val()` which forces it into a 0 when it's not a valid number.  But .. querying within a loop isn't scalable. Instead [use a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723548/8895292) and SUM.

Comment: Yeah some of the values are probably null . I never used that val() function before. Looking it up now.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - You should still consider doing it the right way, with a JOIN. A JOIN is only one query, while querying inside a loop executes a new query for every record in the outer loop - on every request. Making the database work harder than is necessary and it scales poorly.

Comment: I'm weak on joins. Is there a good tutorial on them. My brain hurts looking at your suggested code. :)

Comment: (Update) Lots of them. [One picked at random](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join) Did you try either query? ;-) IF I didn't make a typo they should "just work". The 1st one is if you want = "total per ticket_id", the 2nd is if you want "total for ALL tickets".

Comment: Trying your examples yes. Also trying to edumecate myself on JOINS. Fun stuff.

Comment: Yeah, do read up on joins. Aggregating data is what db's do best. Using proper joins usually leads to much simpler, more peformant code.

Comment: Weak on joins?  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message suggests, you're using a string where an array is expected. In other words, ArraySum() expects an array, but you're passing in a string. Technically a query column is an array behind the scenes, but apparently ArraySum isn't designed to treat it that way. In this case CF treats `resPaymentTotals.payment_amount` as shortcut for the 1st value in the payment_amount column, which is a simple value, not an array.

While you could make the current code work, querying within looping is very inefficient. What you really need is a JOIN, not a loop. To calculate the total - per ticket_id - in a single query:

```
<cfquery>
SELECT ct.ticket_id, SUM(p.payment_amount) AS TotalSales
FROM   closed_tickets ct LEFT JOIN payments p ON ct.ticket_id = p.ticket_id
WHERE  ct.closed_date >= '2017-01-01'
AND    ct.closed_date < '2018-01-01'
AND    ct.ticket_type = 'residential'
GROUP BY ct.ticket_id
</cfquery>
```

If you want the overall total for *all* tickets, just omit ticket_id from the SELECT.

```
<cfquery>
SELECT  SUM(p.payment_amount) AS TotalSales
FROM   closed_tickets ct LEFT JOIN payments p ON ct.ticket_id = p.ticket_id
WHERE  ct.closed_date >= '2017-01-01'
AND    ct.closed_date < '2018-01-01'
AND    ct.ticket_type = 'residential'
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use one query, and like Ageax said, just `JOIN` the tables. When you do this, you'll have to account for the duplicated primary table rows that you may get.

For the SQL:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9de4f/1)

**This Setup is assuming MS SQL Server.** It can be ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE closed_tickets ( 
      ticket_ID int identity
    , closed_date date
    , ticket_type varchar(50) 
) ;
INSERT INTO closed_tickets (closed_date, ticket_type)
VALUES 
      ('2017-01-01','residential')
    , ('2017-01-02','commercial')
    , ('2017-01-03','residential')
    , ('2017-07-01','residential') /* No Payments */
    , ('2018-02-01','residential')
;

CREATE TABLE payment_amount ( 
      payment_ID int identity
    , ticket_id int
    , amount decimal(12,2) 
) ;
INSERT INTO payment_amount(ticket_id, amount)
VALUES 
      ( 1, 100.50 )
    , ( 2, 50.00 ) 
    , ( 3, 50.00 ) 
    , ( 2, null ) 
    , ( 1, 10.00 ) 
    , ( 2, 0.50 ) 
    , ( 1, 20.00 ) 
    , ( 2, 75.00 ) 
    , ( 5, 500.00 )
    , ( 3, 5 ) 
    , ( 3, null ) 
    , ( 3, 25 ) 
;
```

**The Query**:

```
<cfquery name="resTotals" datasource="#datasource#">
    SELECT ct.ticket_ID
      , sum(COALESCE(pa.amount,0))  AS totalPaymentAmount
      , sum(pa.amount)  AS badPaymentAmount /* What about NULLs? */
    FROM closed_tickets ct
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_amount pa ON ct.ticket_ID = pa.ticket_ID
    WHERE ct.ticket_type = 'residential'
      AND year(ct.closed_date) = 2017   /* year() returns INT *//* And you lose index use */
    GROUP BY ct.ticket_ID
</cfquery>
```

**[This Gives You](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9de4f/1/0)**:

```
| ticket_ID | totalPaymentAmount | badPaymentAmount |
|-----------|--------------------|------------------|
|         1 |              130.5 |            130.5 |
|         3 |                 80 |               80 |
|         4 |                  0 |           (null) |
```

So now I assume you'll be doing something with those ticket_IDs; probably looping through them. *Note: I'd rename the query to be descriptive of the data you're returning. We changed its definition.*

```
<cfloop query="resTotals"> 
    [DO STUFF]

    Amount of Sales: $ #totalPaymentAmount)#
</cfloop>
```

Note `ticket_id` 3 and 4, and differences between their `totalPamentAmount` and `badPaymentAmount`. Both have a `NULL` value for a payment: 3 has an explicit `NULL` and 4 has an implicit `NULL` since there are no matching rows. Normally, if you add `1+NULL`, you'll get `NULL`, since `NULL` has no value; you want `1+0` instead. SQL `sum()` will account for the explicit `NULL`, but not for an implicit `NULL`. For the implicit `NULL`, we can use `coalesce()` to return the first non-`NULL` value. Then we can sub `0` for `NULL` and do math for `totalPaymentAmount`.

Comment: And again, if you are working with a lot of data, and you have a database index on `closed_date`, you'll lose the use of that index by using `year()`. If so, I'd once again recommend using a calendar table.

Comment: Yeah, normally a plain SUM() will just discard NULL's in the final calculation, but you're right then end result could be NULL. So actively handling them with coalesce(), isnull(), etc... is a better practice. +1 about functions and indexes.